# Is there a way to reference a target specific variable in a Makefile's Rule?

Tags: makefile, target

```
1 target foo : src = foo.c
2 target foo : obj = foo.o
3 target bar : src = bar.c
4 target bar : obj = bar.o

5 foo bar: obj   # problem - not recognizing obj!
6    @echo link ${bin}     
7    @gcc command to link ${obj}

8 foo.o bar.o
9    @echo compile ${src}
10   @gcc command to compile ${src}
```

So, target specific variable are great for the target recipe as used in lines 6,7,9 & 10.  However, is there a way I can reference the target specific variable "obj" in the target rule itself as i have in line 5?  I'm thinking there is, but I need some voodoo symbol to reference it.  Can't believe I couldn't find this answer anywhere.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

foo bar: $$(obj)
    ...
```

Comment: Oh wow..  this SECONDEXPANSION is new to me. Enables exactly what I want to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want prerequisites, rather than target specific variables:

```
foo : foo.o
bar : bar.o

foo bar :
    gcc -o $@ $^ ${LDFLAGS } ${LDLIBS}

# use the default rule for .c to .o
```

Note that `$^` expands to the list of all prerequisites.

Comment: 4 days ago I was Make-illiterate. This isn't exactly what I need here, but expanded my knowledge nevertheless.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeffGoguen The values of target specific variables are only available within rules. So are prerequisites. If you want to separate different types of prerequisites into groups you can use `filter`, e.g. `$(filter %.o,$^)` yields all `.o` prerequisites.